# Table data backup through unix script

Tags: oracle, unix

I m creating a unix script for our prod enviornment. Requirement is to create a backup of table (not the entire table) few rows. Perform some operation on table(update and delete). At end delete new data and restore back. Problem is how to take backup in prod enviornment. I cant have temp table there.

Script it something like this.

```
spool below query
select 'insert into <tablename> values ( ' || col_1 || ','|| col_2 || ','|| col_3 .. so on
from <tablename> <where condition>  --- generate backup

perform operation on table <delete/update>

delete new values 

Restore backup executing spool file
```

I find this appoarch kind of tedious, is there any better way to accomplish this task?

Note :- This script will be executed in prod where I dont have access to create table. Can perform only update/delete on given table.

Database - 10g

Comment: What is the functional reason to take out "a few rows" of data before the update/delete statements? Would it be possible to rewrite the update/delete statements to exclude these rows?

Comment: Business functionality is to update rows, execute informatica workflow, workflow will execute based on updated rows then revert earlier data for regular workflow execution. Script will run on ad hoc basis.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to introduce a copy of the table. That is much more robust. See if you can bend the rule to include an extra table on production to support ad hoc corrections.

Answer (score 0):

The less tedious way is to use the temporary table approach unfortunately, preferably in a different schema of course. Keeping all the operations and data in the database will be faster and more simple to code, and more reliable.

Alternatively you could use [FLASHBACK TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9012.htm) if this is not a lengthy timescale and no other changes occur on the data. If other changes do occur then it would only be slightly more complex to use a [flashback query clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) to restore the old data.

Comment: Thnx david but I cant take data into othr schema. You know prod server data. Also, there will be big process to give read access to prod schema. Will find more info on flashback table to see if that can fulfill our requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately organisations often lose sight of the purpose of their rules. In this case, disallowing the temporary saving of this data inside the database actually works against the purposes of all of their production system protections. On the other hand, I don't think that anyone believes that organisations generally make particularly good choices.